# File scrlayer-scrpage.sty cannot be found

Tags: packages, koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

The following code leads to an error

```
! LaTeX Error: File `scrlayer-scrpage.sty' not found.
```

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10,a4paper,twoside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline,footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{a4}

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\KOMAoptions{BCOR=2mm,DIV=15}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\cfoot{Le pied de page}
\lehead{En haut à gauche pair}
\lohead{En haut à gauche impair}
\cehead{centre pair}
\cohead{centre impair}

\begin{document}
My first latex document

Hello world !
\end{document}
```

I don't understand why since KOMA-script is installed (if I remove the `scrlayer-scrpage` line, it works). I run pdftex under Mac OSX 10.9.1
(pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)).

What should I do to use `scrlayer-scrpage` package ?

**EDIT: THE SOLUTION**

As indicated in comments, the problem came from an incomplete update of the packages. So contacting the responsible for scrlayer-scrpage package was the solution, and then update your installation.

Comment: You should update to the latest KOMA-Script version 3.12.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. You can update KOMA-Script, as @Speravir, suggests by updating your installation of TeX using `tlmgr` (or a GUI wrapper if MacTeX provides one - I'm assuming you're using MacTeX). In Terminal, you would write `sudo tlmgr update --all` and give your password.

Comment: I forgot it totally, cfr forgot the link, so: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: And since `scrlayer-scrpage` is the successor of `scrpage2` you do not need at all to load the latter.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the underlying issue is caused by an outdated version of KOMA-Script.

Comment: Thanks for the very fast replies ! @Speravir: Yes I agree, because KOMA-script was not up-to-date when I asked it. So what should I do ? Shall I remove the question ?

Comment: I now have the following error: LaTeX Error: Command \scr@fnt@headtopline already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

Comment: Solved: one should remove the scrpage2 package declaration

Comment: @lauhub: It’s your choice, whether you want to delete the question. But I want to advice you not to do this. It could be useful for others, despite it is marked as off-topic.

Comment: @Speravir, can you pls have a look at this post http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199167/how-to-fix-the-compilation-failure-in-this-mwe-in-koma-script