# How to fix this MWE to show the chapterthumbs in KOMA-Script?

Tags: texlive, compiling, koma-script, chapterthumb, scrlayer-scrpage

the compilation failure of the whole dissertation was narrowed down to this MWE below. For some reason the MWE fails to compile with the log file below:

**MWE**
This MWE is related to this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184011/how-to-get-chapterthumbs-match-their-chapter-titles-in-koma-script) and this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198314/bleed-correction-for-chapterthumbs-in-koma) which was *successfully compiled* by other users or machines but not on mine anymore after updating TexLive to 2014.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, twoside=semi]{scrbook} % A4 is 210mm x 297mm
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{calc}%
\usepackage{chapterthumb}% package should be installed in the same active folder
\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage{nameref}%
\usepackage{totcount}
\regtotcounter{chapter}%
%=====================Bibliography=============================
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@article{rand_objective_1971,
    title = {Objective criteria for the evaluation of clustering methods},
    volume = {66},
    pages = {846},
    number = {336},
    journaltitle = {Journal of the American Statistical Association},
    author = {Rand, William M.},
    date = {1971}
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}
%=========================Chapter thumbs========================
\AtBeginDocument{%
\ifnumequal{\number\totvalue{chapter}}{0}{%
\renewcommand{\chapterthumbwidth}{\paperheight}%
\renewcommand{\chapterthumbskip}{\paperheight}%
}{%
\typeout{There are \number\totvalue{chapter} chapter in this document}%
\renewcommand{\chapterthumbskip}{\paperheight/\number\totvalue{chapter}}%
\renewcommand{\chapterthumbwidth}{\paperheight/\number\totvalue{chapter}}%
}%
}%

\lohead[\putchapterthumb]{\putchapterthumb}
\addtokomafont{chapterthumb}{\bfseries}

\newrobustcmd{\SetChapterThumbHeader}{%
\lohead[\putchapterthumb]{\putchapterthumb}%
}%

\newrobustcmd{\ClearChapterThumbHeader}{%
\lohead[]{}%
}%

\newrobustcmd{\refcommand}[1]{%
\nameref*{#1}%
}%

\newtoggle{UseChapterThumb}%
\toggletrue{UseChapterThumb}%

\renewcommand*{\chapterthumbformat}{\refcommand{chapter::title::\number\value{chapter}}}%

\makeatletter

\newcounter{totalchaptercounter}%

\newrobustcmd{\CreateUniqueChapterLabel}[1]{% 
\refstepcounter{totalchaptercounter}%
\label{chapter::title::\number\value{totalchaptercounter}}%
}%


\let\LaTeXStandardChapter\chapter%

\newcommand{\chapter@noopt}[1]{%
\iftoggle{UseChapterThumb}{\SetChapterThumbHeader}{\ClearChapterThumbHeader}
\LaTeXStandardChapter{#1}%
\CreateUniqueChapterLabel{#1}%
}%

\newcommand{\chapter@opt}[2][]{%
\iftoggle{UseChapterThumb}{\SetChapterThumbHeader}{\ClearChapterThumbHeader}
\LaTeXStandardChapter[#1]{#2}%
\CreateUniqueChapterLabel{#2}% Must appear after chapter title is done
}%


\newcommand{\unstarredchapter}{%
\@ifnextchar[{\chapter@opt}{\chapter@noopt}%
}%

\newcommand{\starredchapter}[1]{%
\ClearChapterThumbHeader% Clear the headers -> no chapterthumb here 
\LaTeXStandardChapter*{#1}%   
}%

\renewcommand{\chapter}{%
\@ifstar{\starredchapter}{\unstarredchapter}%
}%


\let\LaTeXStandardTOC\tableofcontents%
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
\begingroup%
\renewcommand{\chapter}{\LaTeXStandardChapter}%
\LaTeXStandardTOC%
\endgroup%
}%


\let\LaTeXStandardLOF\listoffigures%
\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{%
\begingroup%
\renewcommand{\chapter}{\LaTeXStandardChapter}
\LaTeXStandardLOF%
\endgroup
}%

\let\LaTeXStandardLOT\listoftables%
\renewcommand{\listoftables}{%
\begingroup%
\renewcommand{\chapter}{\LaTeXStandardChapter}
\LaTeXStandardLOT%
\endgroup
}%


\let\LaTeXStandardPrintBibliography\printbibliography%


\newrobustcmd{\commonprintbibliographysetup}[1][]{%
\iftoggle{UseChapterThumb}{\SetChapterThumbHeader\refstepcounter{chapter}}{\ClearChapterThumbHeader}
\LaTeXStandardPrintBibliography[#1]
\iftoggle{UseChapterThumb}{%
\immediate\write\@auxout{%
\string\newlabel{chapter::title::\number\value{chapter}}{{\thepage}{\thepage}{Bibliography}{}}%
}%
}{}%
}%



\newrobustcmd{\printbibliography@@noopt}{%
\commonprintbibliographysetup[]%
}%

\newrobustcmd{\printbibliography@@opt}[1][]{%
\commonprintbibliographysetup[#1]%
}

\renewcommand{\printbibliography}{%
\@ifnextchar[{\printbibliography@@opt}{\printbibliography@@noopt}%
}%

\makeatother
%==================================================
\title{Title of the Dissertation}
\author{Author Name} 
\publishers{Faculty Name}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\cleardoublepage

\chapter*{Acknowledgments}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgments}

\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\cleardoublepage
\lohead[\putchapterthumb]{\putchapterthumb}
\mainmatter
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\chapter{Introduction}
\begin{figure}
\caption{dummy figure}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Materials \& Methods} 

\chapter{Results} 
\begin{table}
\caption{dummy table}
\end{table}

\chapter{Discussion}
In his reference \parencite{rand_objective_1971}, the author did a nice job.
\backmatter
\cleardoublepage
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

**Log file snippet**

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99991 (TeX Live 2014/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex 2014.9.2)  2 SEP 2014 20:07
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**MWE_bleed_interaction.tex
(./MWE_bleed_interaction.tex
.
.
.
\c@section@level=\count114
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 353.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 353.
)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/totcount/totcount.sty
Package: totcount 2011/01/25 v1.2 package for gettingthe total value of LaTeX c
ounters
)
\c@chapter@totc=\count115
.
.
.
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filecontents/filecontents.sty
Package: filecontents 2011/10/08 v1.3 Create an external file from within a LaT
eX document
)

LaTeX Warning: Overwriting file `./jobname.bib'.

\openout15 = `jobname.bib'.


! Undefined control sequence.
l.38 \lohead
            [\putchapterthumb]{\putchapterthumb}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.38 \lohead[
             \putchapterthumb]{\putchapterthumb}
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.38 \lohead[\putchapterthumb
                             ]{\putchapterthumb}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.38 \lohead[\putchapterthumb]{\putchapterthumb
                                               }
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

\c@totalchaptercounter=\count233
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'english'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'english.lbx' found.
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx
File: english.lbx 2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
)
Normal \count register pool exhausted, switching to extended pool.
\@quotelevel=\count277
\@quotereset=\count278

(./MWE_bleed_interaction.aux)
\openout1 = `MWE_bleed_interaction.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 156.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 156.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 156.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 156.
.
.
.   
 [5] [6


]
! Undefined control sequence.
\ClearChapterThumbHeader ->\lohead 
                                   []{}
l.165 \chapter*{Acknowledgments}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

[7] [8


]
! Undefined control sequence.
\ClearChapterThumbHeader ->\lohead 
                                   []{}
l.168 \chapter*{Abstract}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

[9] [10


] [11] [12


]
! Undefined control sequence.
l.171 \lohead
             [\putchapterthumb]{\putchapterthumb}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.171 \lohead[\putchapterthumb
                              ]{\putchapterthumb}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.171 \lohead[\putchapterthumb]{\putchapterthumb
                                                }
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

[13] [14


]
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \undefinedpagestyle 

l.173 \pagestyle{scrheadings}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\SetChapterThumbHeader ->\lohead 
                                 [\putchapterthumb ]{\putchapterthumb }
l.175 \chapter{Introduction}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\SetChapterThumbHeader ...ohead [\putchapterthumb 
                                                  ]{\putchapterthumb }
l.175 \chapter{Introduction}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\SetChapterThumbHeader ...humb ]{\putchapterthumb 
                                                  }
l.175 \chapter{Introduction}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

[1] [2


]
Chapter 1.
! Undefined control sequence.
\SetChapterThumbHeader ->\lohead 
                                 [\putchapterthumb ]{\putchapterthumb }
l.180 \chapter{Materials \& Methods}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\SetChapterThumbHeader ...ohead [\putchapterthumb 
                                                  ]{\putchapterthumb }
l.180 \chapter{Materials \& Methods}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\SetChapterThumbHeader ...humb ]{\putchapterthumb 
                                                  }
l.180 \chapter{Materials \& Methods}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

[3] [4


]
Chapter 2.
! Undefined control sequence.
\SetChapterThumbHeader ->\lohead 
                                 [\putchapterthumb ]{\putchapterthumb }
l.182 \chapter{Results}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\SetChapterThumbHeader ...ohead [\putchapterthumb 
                                                  ]{\putchapterthumb }
l.182 \chapter{Results}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\SetChapterThumbHeader ...humb ]{\putchapterthumb 
                                                  }
l.182 \chapter{Results}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

[5] [6


]
Chapter 3.
! Undefined control sequence.
\SetChapterThumbHeader ->\lohead 
                                 [\putchapterthumb ]{\putchapterthumb }
l.187 \chapter{Discussion}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\SetChapterThumbHeader ...ohead [\putchapterthumb 
                                                  ]{\putchapterthumb }
l.187 \chapter{Discussion}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\SetChapterThumbHeader ...humb ]{\putchapterthumb 
                                                  }
l.187 \chapter{Discussion}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

[7] [8


]
Chapter 4.

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'rand_objective_1971' on page 9 undefined on input line
 188.

[9] [10


]
! Undefined control sequence.
\SetChapterThumbHeader ->\lohead 
                                 [\putchapterthumb ]{\putchapterthumb }
l.191 \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\SetChapterThumbHeader ...ohead [\putchapterthumb 
                                                  ]{\putchapterthumb }
l.191 \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\SetChapterThumbHeader ...humb ]{\putchapterthumb 
                                                  }
l.191 \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 191.

[11


] (./MWE_bleed_interaction.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                MWE_bleed_interaction
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

Package logreq Info: Writing requests to 'MWE_bleed_interaction.run.xml'.
\openout1 = `MWE_bleed_interaction.run.xml'.

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 8513 strings out of 493725
 148335 string characters out of 6149065
 597217 words of memory out of 5000000
 11750 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 8846 words of font info for 31 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1328 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 54i,8n,43p,807b,717s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on MWE_bleed_interaction.pdf (28 pages).
```

**Notes**

- To use the `chapterthumb` in the MWE one should install [KOMA examples](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/examples/KOMA-Script-5/Anhang-B/source) from the latex distribution package manager. the `chapterthumb.sty` resides in the `Angang B` part of the KOMA examples. Additionally, one should copy the `chapterthumb.sty` and paste it in the active `.tex` folder.
- Windows 7 32bit but the same problem was encountered on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS OS.
- TexLive 2014 distribution
- compilation with XeLaTeX
- TexSTudio editor 2.8.2
- Solving this MWE is very critical to me because this will fix the same error my dissertation throws during compilation.

**Update 1**
Adding `\listfiles` to the MWE issued these pkgs:

```
 *File List*
 scrbook.cls    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script document class (book)
scrkbase.sty    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent bas
ics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent b
asics and keyval usage)
  keyval.sty    2014/05/08 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize11pt.clo    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt)
typearea.sty    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (type area)
blindtext.sty    2012/01/06 V2.0 blindtext-Package
  xspace.sty    2009/10/20 v1.13 Space after command names (DPC,MH)
    calc.sty    2007/08/22 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
chapterthumb.sty    2014/01/15 v0.3 unsupported LaTeX package
graphicx.sty    2014/04/25 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
   xetex.def    2014/07/25 v4.03 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (RRM/JK)

   color.sty    2014/04/23 v1.1a Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
scrlayer.sty    31/10/2013 v0.9.1480 package (defining layers and page styles)
etoolbox.sty    2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
 nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
totcount.sty    2011/01/25 v1.2 package for gettingthe total value of LaTeX cou
nters
biblatex.sty    2014/06/25 v2.9a programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex2.sty    2014/06/25 v2.9a programmable bibliographies (biber) (PK/JW/AB
)
  logreq.sty    2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
  logreq.def    2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
  ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  blx-dm.def
biblatex-dm.cfg
blx-compat.def    2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.def    
standard.bbx    2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
 numeric.bbx    2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
 numeric.cbx    2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex citation style (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.cfg    
filecontents.sty    2011/10/08 v1.3 Create an external file from within a LaTeX
 document
 english.lbx    2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
 ***********
```

**Update 2**
[image]

So the KOMA-script is updated.

**Updated Question**
So the code in the MWE worked before because it was based on the `scrpage2` package which is no more supported in the new version of KOMA-Script and that was the source of the errors in the log file. The new `chapterthumb` is based on `scrlayer` instead of the older `scrpage2` package. So how to update the current code to make it comply with the new KOMA version?

Comment: `\lohead` does not exist according to your `.log` file. Where should this be coming from? It seems to deal with placing content in the `l`eft `head`er on `o`dd pages.

Comment: do you know to which package `\lohead` refers? what should be the next step to track down this bug. Did you succeed in compiling it?

Comment: It comes from `\usepackage{scrpage2}` - part of the [KOMA-script bundle](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script).

Comment: the `l`eft `head`er on `o`dd pages are certainly related to the `chapterthumbs`.

Comment: Do you need anything from the 2014 version for your dissertation? If not, compile it using the 2013 version (or whichever you used previously). I think the changes to koma-script are not backwards compatible with the entirety of your code. If your dissertation is more-or-less complete, the last thing you want to worry about it updates screwing things up. So don't use the updated stuff.

Comment: See the example for commands to add to your preamble with the current versions - but I still get errors so I expect you would need to make further changes to your set-up.

Comment: yes I need the 2014 version to fix an issue with the bleed correction of the chapterthumbs. The problem is in the code part which deals with the chapterthumbs set up.

Comment: Phew, that title is sophisticated.

Comment: @Percusse feel free to reduce it.

Comment: I would if I could hehe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your installation is a little bit faulty.

In your `listfile` part is the following missing:

```
scrpage2.sty    2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (page head and foot)
```

Without package `scrpage2`  the command `\lohead` can't work.  That's why you get your error message.

Please check your installation. You can try to use the package manager to update your system.

**Update:**
Can you compile your document after adding `\usepackage{scrpage2}` to your document?

Comment: I did update the whole texlive from manager but nothing changed (scrpage2 didn't show up in the list). Is there any workaround?

Comment: according to http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4231/should-we-convert-the-tag-scrpage2-into-an-alias-for-a-new-tag-scrlayer-crpag  `scrlayer` is the *successor* of scrpage2 in KOMA-script. In this case there should be no problem with the distribution as `scrlayer` appeared in my list. Problem could be some syntax in scrpage2 that is now incompatible with scrlayer?!

Comment: here http://www.komascript.de/chapterthumbs-example the author of `chapterthumb` package states that since edition 5 of `KOMA-script`  the chapterthum is based on `scrlayer` rather than `scrpage2`. the new `chapterthumb` sits in Anhang B here http://www.komascript.de/komascriptbuch

Comment: if you update MikTex distribution would you get the same output?

Comment: the only exit from this problem in my case is to go for the updated version. I am now preparing a new post and a new MWE for this purpose. I need your support.

Comment: adding `\usepackage{scrpage2}` did not solve the problem. pls consider the MWE here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199381/customize-appearance-of-chapterthumbs-scrlayer-version-in-this-mwe

Comment: the updated distribution fixed other issues with the dissertation and would pose no problem for compilation of dissertation in general except for the chapterthumbs. So I am in favor of the updated version of `chapterthumb` and the new post above illustrates the new code that must be adapted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is restricted with the `chapterthumb.sty` package. One can keep the older version of it and do the update to all of TexLive or MikeTex LaTeX system.

- Older version of it depends on the `scrpage2` package part of the KOMA-script bundle
- Newer version as of this date depends rather on `scrlayer` package a successor of `scrpage2`. In this package there is an internal call to the `scrlayer` package instead of `scrpage2` that's why it did appear in the `\listfiles` output in the MWE.

I did manage to fix the problem by simply replacing the older version with the newer one in my working directory *and* in the place where `KOMA-script examples` commonly resides. One can download the newest version by whatever package manager and then replace the newer version with the older version of `chapterthumb.sty` in the folder of installation. If you install it via the package manager of TexLive you should have it in this path:
 `C:\texlive\2014\texmf-dist\doc\latex\koma-script-examples\Anhang-B`

Just in case on would need the older version of the `chapterthumbs` package and would like to make use of the code posted in the previous posts, here is the package code that depends on the `scrpage2` package (copy it and rename the file to `chapterthumbs.sty` :

```
% chapterthumb.sty
% Copyright 2008 Markus Kohm
% 
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
% The latest version of this license is in
% http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
% version 2005/12/01 or later.
% 
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status `maintained'.
% 
% The Current Maintainer of this work is Markus Kohm.
% 
% This work consists of this file only.
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
\ProvidesPackage{chapterthumb}% [2005/03/10 v0.1 unsupported LaTeX package]
\DeclareOption*{%
  \PassOptionsToPackage{\CurrentOption}{scrpage2}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\RequirePackage{graphics,color}
\RequirePackage{scrpage2}
\newcommand*{\putchapterthumb}{%
  \begingroup
    \makebox[0pt][l]{%
      \hspace{-\oddsidemargin}\hspace{-1in}%
      \hspace{-\@oddheadshift}%
      \hspace{\paperwidth}%
      \parbox[t][0pt][t]{0pt}{%
        \vspace{-\topmargin}%
        \vspace{-1in}%
        \vspace{-\headheight}%
        \vspace{\dp\strutbox}%
        \vspace{\firstchapterthumbskip}%
        \setlength{\@tempdima}{\paperheight}%
        \addtolength{\@tempdima}{-\chapterthumbwidth}%
        \addtolength{\@tempdima}{1pt}%
        \setlength{\@tempdimb}{\chapterthumbskip}%
        \divide\@tempdima by\@tempdimb
        \@tempcnta=\@tempdima
        \advance\@tempcnta by 1
        \@tempcntb=\value{chapter}%
        \advance\@tempcntb by -1
        \divide\@tempcntb by \@tempcnta
        \multiply\@tempcntb by -\@tempcnta
        \advance\@tempcntb by \value{chapter}%
        \advance\@tempcntb by -1
        \setlength{\@tempdima}{\chapterthumbskip}%
        \vspace{\@tempcntb\@tempdima}%
        \makebox[0pt][r]{%
          \rotatebox{90}{%
            \colorbox{\chapterthumbboxcolor}{%
              \parbox[t][\chapterthumbheight][c]%
                     {\chapterthumbwidth}{%
                \centering
                \color{\chapterthumbcolor}%
                \chapterthumbfont{\chapterthumbformat}}}}}%
      }%
    }%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand*{\firstchapterthumbskip}{0pt}
\newcommand*{\chapterthumbheight}{2em}
\newcommand*{\chapterthumbwidth}{.2\paperheight}%
\newcommand*{\chapterthumbskip}{.1\paperheight}%
\newcommand*{\chapterthumbboxcolor}{black}%
\newcommand*{\chapterthumbcolor}{white}
\newcommand*{\chapterthumbformat}{\@chapapp~\thechapter}
\newcommand*{\chapterthumbfont}{\normalfont\Large\sffamily}
\newcommand*{\scr@fnt@chapterthumb}{\chapterthumbfont}
\endinput
%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: "chapterthumbexample"
%%% End:
```