# Fedora user and messed up texlive, tlmgr not working. classicthesis doesn't work too

Tags: texlive, classicthesis

I recently naively removed my old texlive to fresh install a new full-scheme one. tlmgr seems dead since then. echo PATH$ing it:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/peppe/.local/bin:/home/peppe/bin
```

i think i see the issue here, i have no longer any usr/local/texlive/ folder. How do i fix things up?

I wish i could fix tlmgr up since i'm trying to compile [this](http://codepaste.net/9fmg1g) simple classicthesis template while receiving `! LaTeX Error: File 'scrlayer-scrpage.sty' not found.` and i've just read [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160160/file-scrlayer-scrpage-sty-cannot-be-found) updating my KOMA-script libraries should do the job.

Oh i miss my mac and MacTex, goddamn fedora and texlive linux managing. Please help me linux/latex saviours, i should be already writing my thesis :'(!

Comment: You told us that you don't have an /usr/local/texlive folder anymore, but didn't tell us in which folder TeXlive is actually installed now. However, I think the easiest (but not the best) solution is setting up a symbolic link from /usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-linux to the new directory, i.e. "mkdir -p /usr/local/texlive/2012/bin", "cd /usr/local/texlive/2012/bin", and "ln -s <new location of TeXlive>/bin/x86_64-linux .". (It seems that you don't know where the path to the TeXlive folder is set, because changing this to the new location would be the better solution.)

Comment: Hey Axel, thanks for your comment! check my comment at shari137's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well to see if you have tlmgr and where it is:

locate tlmgr

(I assumed that you have the locate command, otherwise install it; I'm pretty sure that Fedora has it, I checked a bit) or:

which tlmgr

The second one will work only if tlmgr is in your PATH. So the first one does the job. If you installed texlive and didn't reboot your pc since then, 'locate tlmgr' won't find it. In this case you first have to do 'sudo updatedb' or reboot your pc. You have to run updatedb also in the case you had to install locate.
At this point try:

tlmgr update --list (or --all)

If it doesn't work, try doing with sudo and giving the full path to tlmgr, for example in my pc I would do:

sudo /usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr update --all

I remember that after installing texlive 2014 tlmgr dind't work giving only 'tlmgr update --list' but I had to use sudo and the full path to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! locate is not responding. asking for which get me `/usr/bin/which: no tlmgr in (/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/peppe/.local/bin:/home/peppe/bin)`. I misteriously have no /usr/loca/texlive folder but i have one at /usr/share/texlive containing no 2014 folder : \

Comment: Since you can compile LaTeX documents, you can generate log files by compiling a LaTeX document. Take a look at the generated log file to see where your LaTeX packages are installed, they are listed there with full path. (To me it sounds like you do not have installed TeXlive manually but from the Fedora repositories instead. This is a bad idea since the TeXlive from Fedora is usually outdated and does not offer tlmgr. In this case I would recommend to install TeXlive 2015 manually to /usr/local/texlive.)

Comment: Yep, i've installed from fedora repository. I'll sudo remove it and try a new fresh install following [this](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html). I'll let you know in a few hours. Thanks :)